# Architect sync Store to WebService

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, submit

I want to sync my settings, which have been edited in some fields of a form, to the server.

Firebug shows: NOTHING, no connection at click on Button.
JavaScript Console shows: NO ERROR.

What I have:

```
onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    Ext.getStore("optionsStore").getAt(0).setDirty();
    Ext.getStore("optionsStore").commitChanges();
    Ext.getStore("optionsStore").sync();
}
```

I use to load:

```
onJsonstoreLoad: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
    Ext.getCmp("optionsForm").getForm().loadRecord(store.getAt(0));
}
```

My store was built with architect:

```
constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'optionsModel',
        storeId: 'optionsStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            api: 'read: \'http://localhost:52699/api/AdminPanel?do=select\',\r\ncreate: \'http://localhost:52699/api/AdminPanel?do=insert\',\r\nupdate: \'http://localhost:52699/api/AdminPanel?do=update\',\r\ndestroy: \'http://localhost:52699/api/AdminPanel?do=delete\'',
            url: 'allSettings.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'globalSettings'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                allowSingle: false,
                encode: true,
                root: 'globalSettings'
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            load: {
                fn: me.onJsonstoreLoad,
                scope: me
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an easy one:

```
onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    Ext.getCmp("optionsForm").getForm().updateRecord(Ext.getStore("optionsStore").getAt(0));
    Ext.getStore("optionsStore").getAt(0).setDirty();
    Ext.getStore("optionsStore").commitChanges();
    Ext.getStore("optionsStore").sync();
}
```